# Django 1.5 custom user model - signals limitation

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-1.5

It's written [in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-signals) that:

> Another limitation of custom User models is that you can’t use django.contrib.auth.get_user_model() as the sender or target of a signal handler. Instead, you must register the handler with the resulting User model. See Signals for more information on registering an sending signals.

I guess it means you can do the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_saved(sender=None, instance=None, **kwargs):
    # something
```

Isn't it? I'm just wondering if I understand well (I don't understand why they say it's a "limitation", but whatever, just want to check).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work.
I think they mean to use the same function as sender

in doc:

> as the **sender** or **target** of a signal handler. Instead, **you must register**
>   the handler **with the resulting User model**

Answer (score 6):

It's because the object hasn't been "installed" when the signal is being created so get_user_model() can't find the object that it needs to attach the signal handler.

See [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19218) for the details on how it was found and what the problem is.

Your example wouldn't work because the `get_user_model()` call would fail for this reason. For now the only way to make a signal handler work with a custom User class is to name it directly without using `get_user_model()`, eg

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=myapp.MyUserModel) # can't use get_user_model() here
def user_saved(sender=None, instance=None, **kwargs):
    # something
```

Your coding style could also do with some work: when you run `User = get_user_model()`, that creates a variable called `User` with its value set to the results of the `get_user_model()` function call. Python convention (and that of most other languages) is for normal variables to start with a lower-case letter and for classes to start with an upper case letter.

So `user = get_user_model()` and then using the `user` variable later on would make much more sense to anyone reading your code and would help to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: Not sure what you're meaning about lower-case letters, User in this case is callable, or is a class, however you call that. Also, your point is right **when using get_user_model in the same models.py that the AUTH_USER_MODEL**. This is a good point, but your message is not clear

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` or any model as a string, e.g. `'users.MyCustomUser'`:

```
def user_post_save_handler(**kwargs):
    # do something
post_save.connect(user_post_save_handler, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: your method is giving error while creating profile AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: @Lord-shiV Seems you are doing something like `'foo'.objects.whatever()` in your code. Please check your code inside your handler function.