# Django custom user, how to get signals to work in 1.5

Tags: django-signals, django-1.5

I'm using Django 1.5, which allows custom users. I already got the custom users to work on its own.
I'd like to add a new model Blah whenever a custom user is created (aka use signals to do this).

currently, I have in signals.py

```
from group.models import Blah
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from customuser.models import EmailUser
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=EmailUser)
def user_saved(sender=None, instance=None, **kwargs):
    user = kw["instance"]
        print("Request finished!")
        if kw["created"]:
            blah = Blah(user=user)
            blah.save()
```

in settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customuser.EmailUser'
```

As of now, when I'm using Django admin to create a new email user. After I create the EmailUser though, it does not create a new Blah.

I referenced: [Django 1.5 custom user model - signals limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226632/django-1-5-custom-user-model-signals-limitation) 
Following this method did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `user = kw["instance"]` and `kw["created"]` with `kwargs["instance"]` and `kwargs["created"]` and instead of

```
def user_saved(sender=None, instance=None, **kwargs):
```

use :

```
def user_saved(sender, **kwargs):
```

another thing I do is instead of using the @reciever view wrapper I put the following code at the end of my signals.py file.

```
post_save.connect(user_saved, sender=EmailUser)
```

One more thing is to make sure you import the signals file in your urls.py file as well so they actually get loaded.

```
from yourApp import signals
```