# Django app post_save with sender=get_user_model()

Tags: django, signals

I have a Django app that needs to receive the post_save signal when the user model is saved, without knowing about the main project directly. Here's the basic layout:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    models.py
app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    signals.py
```

It must work with Django 1.6, so I can't use the ready() method. In `app/__init__.py` I have:

```
# app/__init__.py

import signals
```

And in `app/signals.py`:

```
# app/signals.py

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def user_save_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ...
```

The installed apps in `project/settings` include:

```
# project/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'project',
    'app',
    ...
```

The custom user model is defined in `project/models.py`. The signals module is definitely being loaded with the correct user model (a quick print statement at the top of signals.py serves to demonstrate this).

However, my callback function never gets called when an instance of the user model is saved. The django-debug-toolbar helped me to verify that the receivers are not being registered. What gives? Any thoughts you might have are greatly appreciated ;)

----- EDIT -----

It ended up being a silly problem, so I'm not posting it as an Answer. It's a large project and there was another signal receiver somewhere else with the same name. The other one was getting defined after mine, which was overwriting it in the registry of receivers :P

I guess it's a lesson in naming conventions... If you're going to register a signal handler, name it something specific. Especially if there are multiple handlers for the same signal.

Comment: Could you show the order of apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @alecxe - I assume you're wondering what order the apps were in. I updated the question to elucidate that point.

Comment: Thanks, but where is `django.contrib.auth`?

Comment: Good point - it's above the other apps.

Comment: Looks like you are experiencing [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16541458/771848).

Comment: But if I put `print(get_user_model())` at the top of `app/signals.py`, it correctly outputs `<class 'project.models.User'>`, which seems to suggest that the apps are being installed in the correct order, and that it is able to correctly determine the user model. Maybe something changed since Django 1.5?

Answer (score 3):

I just updated a project from 1.7 to 1.8 and ran into this issue.

I was replacing old `'auth.User'`and `django.contrib.auth.models.User`references and stumbled upon the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Reading through the traceback I found out that I did the following in my `models.py`:

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=get_user_model())
```

This is the second time I got that issue, so the following might be a solution to others. Simply replace the `get_user_model`function with a string or setting:

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: I'm new to django. This saved my day. Currently I'm using `sender='auth.User' `.  One thing that I wanted to implement was have a dynamic user model that you cater for `email login` and `username login` based on api that is being queried. Not sure if that is even possible. Might have problem with setting the sender to string then.